# Can we download parts of a S3 multipart upload which has failed

Tags: java, c#, .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I wonder what happens and what can be done when a multi-part upload fails due to a connection issue. Can I access file parts which managed to get uploaded to my S3-Compatible-Storage bucket? Is it possible to download those parts?

Thanks!

(tried to upload/download object parts of a multi-part upload via .net sdk)

Comment: The object in S3 is not available for download, even parts of it, until it is completely uploaded.